# Using a CASE statement in a SQL Server WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to change the `WHERE` clause depending how many persons that exist in each State or City.

If there are more then 10 people in a state I want the `WHERE` to be:

```
WHERE u.StateID = @StateID
```

If there are more then 10 people in a city I want it to be:

```
WHERE u.CityID = @CityID
```

instead of

```
WHERE u.StateID = @StateID
```

If there aren't more then 10 people in either city or state I want it to be:

```
WHERE u.CountryID = '1'



ALTER PROCEDURE GetHighscore
(@UserID int)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @StateCount int
Declare @CityCount int
Declare @StateID int
Declare @CityID int

SELECT @StateID=StateID FROM tblUser WHERE UserID = @UserID

SELECT @CityID=CityID FROM tblUser WHERE UserID = @UserID

SELECT  @StateCount=COUNT(DISTINCT tblUserTrix.UserID)
FROM            tblUserTrix INNER JOIN
                         tblUser ON tblUserTrix.UserID = tblUser.UserID
WHERE        (tblUser.StateID = @StateID)

SELECT @CityCount=COUNT(DISTINCT tblUserTrix.UserID)
FROM            tblUserTrix INNER JOIN
                         tblUser ON tblUserTrix.UserID = tblUser.UserID
WHERE        (tblUser.CityID = @CityID)


SELECT TOP 10        ut.UserID, SUM(t.Hardness) AS TotalTrixPoints, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.StateID, u.CityID, tblSweCitys.CityName
FROM            tblUserTrix AS ut INNER JOIN
                         tblUser AS u ON ut.UserID = u.UserID INNER JOIN
                         tblState ON u.StateID = tblState.StateID INNER JOIN
                         tblCitys ON u.CityID = tblCitys.CityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         tblTrix AS t ON ut.TrixID = t.TrixID

WHERE CASE 
WHEN @StateCount > 10 
THEN u.StateID = @StateID

WHEN @CityCount > 10 
THEN u.CityID = @CityID
ELSE u.CountryID = '1'
        END = ?

GROUP BY ut.UserID, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.CityID, u.StateID, tblCitys.CityName
ORDER BY TotalTrixPoints DESC   

END
```

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea - you would have to find out the number of **people** (that's the proper plural of "person" in English) in a city or state first, before you can decide how to build your SQL statement dynamically ......

Comment: okey, I will try to remember that Marc. The number of people in each city or state do I get from StateCount and CityCount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use AND / OR operators and nested conditions instead of CASE.

```
(@StateCount > 10 AND u.StateID = @StateID) OR (@CityCount > 10 AND CityID = @CityID) OR (CountryID = '1')
```

Some like this.

**UPDADE**:

So, really this example wasn't work properly for you. You need more complex where clause. Try this:

```
(@StateCount > 10 AND u.StateID = @StateID)
OR
(@CityCount > 10 AND @StateCount <= 10 AND CityID = @CityID)
OR
(@StateCount <= 10 AND @CityCount <= 10 AND CountryID = '1')
```

**UPDATE 2**

And this a little better:

```
(@StateCount > 10 AND u.StateID = @StateID)
OR
(@StateCount <= 10 
    AND
    (
        (@CityCount > 10 AND CityID = @CityID)
        OR
        (@CityCount <= 10 AND CountryID = '1')
    )   
)
```

Comment: okey, but even if there is 50 persons in a city, I dont get the highscore for the city becouse there is an OR (CountryID = '1') Everybody has countryID 1. And becouse of that I get everybody in the highscore, not just the city.

Comment: Updated answer. This is full-specified criteria as is. It can be optimized by using nested conditions.